# Can you make your own epoxy grout?

Tags: grout

I've been using it but it's very expensive. The grout powder appears to be normal grout... could I just combine it with some sort of epoxy mix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

echo [Michael](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/26900/41781).  I've used Laticrete's SpectraLock..  There's a lot of engineering there to allow water based haze removal (OK, you do need to add white vinegar, very cheap and non-toxic).  [Spectralock installation](https://cdn.laticrete.com/~/media/product-documents/installation-information/ds-6815.ashx?la=en&vs=1&d=20160216T190308Z)

Off-the-shelf epoxy is going to require a solvent based haze removal (usually lacquer thinner, acetone, or alcohol)..  much more hazardous (indoors you'll need an organic respirator) and adds to the cost.  Checkout [West Systems how to use instructions and videos](http://www.westsystem.com/ss/how-to-use/).

Its doable, but...how many experimental batches are needed to verify proper resin/hardner.filler(grout) ingredient mixes so you get a mix that looks and performs like you want..  There goes your savings..

In the business of grouting tile?  might be worth it.  Doing a one off for a kitchen/bath..  buy a product backed by a warranty, videos, other users (like John Bridges' forum).

Comment: I know this an old post, but it is the only one that comes up on google.  I've worked with a wide variety of epoxies and polyester resins.  I've always used vinegar for clean up.  Acetone is a good thinning agent but vinegar has never failed to clean up.  Sometimes I use it straight without diluting it for maximum strength.  Epoxy is not hard to mix and get correct.  You can add hollow glass microspheres to thicken or for a white color.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it with clear epoxy and micro spheres to create an un-sanded, white colored grout. I used it on a very small, thin glass mosaic tile. Vinegar and water worked but acetone worked better. If you are to use the spectralock part C I would add some white to the epoxy. My objective was to get away from a sanded product.

Comment: that's great! do you have pictures? how smooth is it?

Answer (score 1):

My answer to your question is "Probably Not".

That said you are of course free to experiment. Tryout you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small batch of expoxy grout for a garden project. I mixed epoxy according to package directions and added powdered grout mix until I found the desirable consistency. It worked for my project with the exception of having shiny grout lines.